# Tikz error with ! Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz,bm,color}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

% with errors
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.075]
\draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (-2,0)--(198,0);
\node [below] at (195,0) {\scriptsize{$Q$}};
\draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (0,-2)--(0,158);
\node [left] at (0,155) {\scriptsize{$p$}};
\draw [very thick] (0,100) -- (95,100) to [out=0,in=180] (100,100) to [out=0,in=135] (175,85);
\draw [dashed] (0,65) -- (150,65);
\draw [dash dot] (0,141) to [out=0,in=150] (100,100) to [out=330,in=135 (150,65) to [out=315,in=135] (160,55);
\end{tikzpicture}
%! Dimension too large.

% no errors
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.075]
\draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (-2,0)--(198,0);
\node [below] at (195,0) {\scriptsize{$Q$}};
\draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (0,-2)--(0,158);
\node [left] at (0,155) {\scriptsize{$p$}};
\draw [very thick] (0,100) -- (95,100) -- (100,100) -- (175,85);
\draw [dashed] (0,65) -- (150,65);
\draw [very thick] (0,141) -- (100,100) -- (150,65) -- (160,55);
\end{tikzpicture}
% no errors

\end{document}
```

I can't figure why this is happening?

Comment: without testing it is probably because of the scale of the arrow

Comment: There is also a `[` missing behind `[out=330,in=135`. And size commands don't take arguments, so it should be `\scriptsize $p$`

Comment: scale of the arrow is not solution @percusse

Comment: missing     ] is not solve problem, and    \scripsize $p$ with removing    {} nothing change  @samcarter

Comment: Well, `175cm` is indeed a large dimension. The error is pretty much self-explanatory. :)

Comment: I think the default dimension are cm . Making the length of the arrow head in mm doesn't change the rest of dimensions . So you either add mm to the points or Chang them to cm .

Comment: Dimension cm/mm was probably problem cause. @mostafax80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal example still exhibiting the error is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw (100,100) to [out=0,in=135] (175,85);
\end{document}
```

My guess is that computing the arc causes some overflow; in fact, your picture has a size in the range of one or more square meters.

Since you scale your picture by a factor of 0.075 anyway, I suggest to use a scale factor of 0.75 and reduce the numbers by a factor of 10. The command

```
\tikz\draw (10.0,10.0) to [out=0,in=135] (17.5,8.5);
```

gives no error.

Here is your modified document and the corresponding output. Seems to work.

```
\documentclass[convert={outext=.jpg}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,bm,color}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
  \draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (-0.2,0)--(19.8,0);
  \node [below] at (19.5,0) {\scriptsize{$Q$}};
  \draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (0,-0.2)--(0,15.8);
  \node [left] at (0,15.5) {\scriptsize{$p$}};
  \draw [very thick] (0,10.0) -- (9.5,10.0) to [out=0,in=180]
    (10.0,10.0) to [out=0,in=135] (17.5,8.5);
  \draw [dashed] (0,6.5) -- (15.0,6.5);
  \draw [dash dot] (0,14.1) to [out=0,in=150]
    (10.0,10.0) to [out=330,in=135] (15.0,6.5)
    to [out=315,in=135] (16.0,5.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0mm,y=1.0mm]
  \draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (-2,0)--(98,0);
  \node [below] at (95,0) {\scriptsize{$t$}};
  \draw[-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]},thin] (0,-2)--(0,78);
  \node [left] at (0,75) {\scriptsize{$Q$}};
  \begin{axis}
  [
anchor=origin,
x=0.5mm, y=0.5mm,
hide axis,
xmin = 0, xmax = 190,
ymin = 0, ymax = 150,
  ]
  \addplot[smooth,dash dot] plot coordinates
  {
(0,100)
(100,100)
(175,85)
  };
  \addplot[smooth,very thick] plot coordinates 
  {
(0,141)
(100,100)
(163,55)
  };
  \addplot[smooth,dashed] plot coordinates
  {
(0,65)
(150,65)
  };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This was my finding in meantime.

Comment: Could you explain your solution a bit more? Without any additional comments it will be hard for people that are not so familiar with LaTeX and Friends to find out what exactly made the error disappear.